# Multiple hops impersonation in .NET and web services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, impersonation

I have old school web service and it is configured to impersonate the caller. Works with no problem. Now I am thinking about adding another more higher level ASP.NET (non-wcf) web service which would be calling the original web service.

The question is - will the client identity flow across two hops as in client (1)-> new web service (2)-> old web service) or there will be issues?

Answer (score 0):

I believe unless the new ASP.NET web service impersonates the client, the identity will not flow to the second web service. If there is no impersonation then windows identity of the worker process will be sent to the old service. With impersonation, new service code will run under same user as that of client and then using [DefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials.aspx), you can call the old web service.